# Gridview does not bind to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in the page load...For some reason the dropdown binds to the db, but the gridview that I want to bind is not displayed. What could be the reason for this? Thanks!

C#:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CompanyName, CompanyID FROM Company ORDER BY CompanyName", new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()));
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.ProjectName AS ProjectName, p.Status FROM Project p, Company c WHERE c.CompanyID = p.CompanyID AND c.CompanyID = 3", new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()));

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);

    conn.Close();

    company_list.DataSource = ds;
    company_list.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
    company_list.DataValueField = "CompanyID";
    company_list.DataBind();

    company_list.Items.Insert(0, "-- Please Select Company --");

    cmd2.Connection.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    sqlAdapter.Fill(ds2);

    Gridview1.DataSource = ds2;
    Gridview1.DataBind();

    cmd2.Connection.Close();
    cmd2.Connection.Dispose();
```

ASP.net:

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="True"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">

                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProjectName") %>' CssClass="input input1" ID="project_name" width="150" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status") %>' CssClass="input input1" ID="status" width="150" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>

    </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: is the parameter your taking for `SqlConnection` correct? :`SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());` Shouldn't you be storing your connection string in a string variable and using that variable within your new `SqlConnection`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridView doesn't have any data. Check the query returns something. You might also want to add an [EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx).

Incidentally, the default CommandType is Text, so you don't need to specify that, and you don't need to call Connection.Open, or .Close - the DataAdapter.Fill method takes care of all of that for you. Oh, and you should really use a DataReader, and bind that rather than a DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not set the command type for cmd2.  Why don't you try the following:
First get all the data for the listbox then close the conn object.  Then do this:

```
 conn.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT p.ProjectName AS ProjectName, p.Status FROM   Project p, Company c WHERE c.CompanyID = p.CompanyID AND c.CompanyID = 3", conn);

cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
sqlAdapter.Fill(ds2);

Gridview1.DataSource = ds2;
Gridview1.DataBind();

conn.Close();
```

Comment: Did you verify you actually are returning any rows?